Is there a difference between the -im and -o adverbs?
Some adverbs end in -im and others in -o. For example, there is the adverb furtim and then the (same?) adverb furto, which both apparently mean secretely or stealthily.
Is there any difference between these words or are they exact synonyms?

Are there many cases where both variants exist?
